# Concatenation behaves differently on two servers

Tags: mysql

I have two servers (not master/slaves of each other), each running MySQL 5.1.71-log.

One server 1 (which happens to be in the US), the following query returns good results:

```
select distinct(devicemode || ' - ' || model || ' - ' || version) as a from <TABLE1>, <TABLE2> where <TABLE1>.<FKEY> = <TABLE2>.key and <TABLE1>.key = 1234 order by devicemode ,model,version;
```

The results look like:

```
US - MicroMaxx - 30.80.306.024
```

When the same query is run on server 2 (which happens to be in the UK), I get different results:

```
0
```

If I change the query to be:

```
select distinct(concat(devicemode, ' - ', model,' - ', version) as a from <TABLE1>, <TABLE2> where <TABLE1>.<FKEY> = <TABLE2>.key and <TABLE1>.key = 1234 order by devicemode ,model,version;
```

the same results are returned on both servers:

```
US - MicroMaxx - 30.80.306.024
```

Any idea why there would be a difference?

Thanks

Alan

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most probably the two servers have different [`SQL_MODE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/sql-mode.html) settings.

One has **[`PIPES_AS_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_pipes_as_concat)** defined and the other not. The server that hasn't this setting, treats `||` ("pipes") as a synonym to `OR` and not as the string concatenation operator.

Comment: Sounds plausible to me. +1 !!! Oops, 40 votes already ??? I'll upvote tomorrow.

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA haha, thnx. You do some serious voting, don't you? I don't think I've reached the 40 limit, ever.